# Poner la orientacion de cada html al gusto apache cordova

Tags: apache, cordova

Tengo un proyecto con android apache cordova, solo queria saber si se puede hacer de forma nativa que cada pagina de html que yo tengo le pueda poner una orientacion que yo quiera. Un saludo , he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro nada.

Comment: Si usas un framework como ionic puedes usar el grid para este fin o usando Bootstrap que el grid funciona igual https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/

Comment: Hola Ruben. Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta porque ahora mismo no está claro. Aqui se resuelven dudas basadas en un trabajo e investigacion previa y nos muestras lo intentado y donde ha fallado. Si no sabes por donde empezar, has de seguir buscando o puedes pedir orientacion en el [chat]. Un saludo